# How can us Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow users help with the current Chinese SPAM attack?

Tags: discussion, spam, spam-detection

We love our Stack Exchange and don't like to see it under attack like this.

Many of us are programmers and many of us know stuff about languages, including Chinese. There's probably a good few who are both programmers and know about Chinese and even a few with experience in Bayesian filtering, SPAM detecting, etc.

How can we help?

(I'm seeing the Spam attack on my main site, Travel.SE, which doesn't block Chinese characters like many sites can. I imagine the problem is also bad over at Chinese.SE)

Comment: Well, writing spam detection bots like Smoke Detector is quite helpful. The bot give links to spam automatically, and people in chat go and flag. Those with 200 rep in one site can then flag in any site of Stack Exchange. For example, its activity over the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) today: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MTM2K.png :)